# How to work with RequireJS and its config correctly

Tags: javascript, requirejs, config

I'm having a lot of troubles with `RequireJS`, I get errors simply by using a `define` module.

Let's assume I have this configuration:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/",
    paths: {
        jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min",
        handlebars: "libs/backbone/template/handlebars",
        lodash: "libs/backbone/template/lodash.min",
        backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min",
        helper:"app/helper",
        jquery_cookie:"libs/jquery/plugin/jquery.cookie",
        text:"libs/require/text-2.0.7"
    },
    shim: {
        "lodash": {
            exports: '_'
        },
        "handlebars": {
            deps:["jquery"],
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["helper", "lodash", "handlebars", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});


define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    console.log('define "jquery" on config.js');
    return $;
});
console.log("end config.js");
```

First, I've tried the classic way, I've loaded a `config` file where I have all the dependances of my `JavaScript` files, I'm using `jQuery`, `Backbone` and other libs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="config" src="js/libs/require/require-2.1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {
        console.log("jquery loaded");
    });
</script>
```

With this configuration, i get these errors and logs sequence:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return r}
 > http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch 
end config.js
define "jquery" on config.js
```

It seems the **error** is referred to the function `require.config(...);`

I thought it was a load problem, so I've tried to use the var `require` as described in [RequireJS site](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) without solving it.

The absurd thing is I'm working on a fullscreen app built in `Backbone` with the same configuration without getting any problem, here I need to work more with different views and I cannot start, basically the whole difference is here I'm using `CakePHP`.

Why this won't work, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery version you are using already has AMD support. So you don't have to use shim for it. You can directly give the path and start using it.

Since the module is already defined in the jQuery library, it throws errors when you try to redefine it. The following code tries to define an anonymous module.

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
     console.log('define "jquery" on config.js');
     return $;
});
```

remove the above code and should work fine. The following code uses require method to load the jquery module.

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
     console.log($(document));
});
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've removed it and updated the question, unfortunately it still won't work and throwing the same error.

Comment: The problem is in the following code, define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    console.log('define "jquery" on config.js');
    return $;
}); Try removing it

Comment: define() method is used to define a module. try replacing the 'define' in your code to 'require'.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem, since using jQuery inside define is required for every library needs it like Backbone, to be sure I've removed it as you said and it still throw the error.

Comment: I've faced similar kind issues in my project. I fixed it by removing the redefinitions. But I'm not sure of the problem in your code. one last suggestion, go through the link provided in the error message "http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch" again. It might help.

Comment: One more thought, see if jquery file is loaded anywhere else in your code. you might be including the 'jquery' in cakephp somewhere.

Comment: I've got the problem, if I set `define` methods inside `config.js` it won't work, if I move the define **inside** `.js` files it works, shouldn't config.js contain base define I can use around my website? Am I really forced to use this useless external file?

Comment: The file that contains the config for require should not contain any module definition. Its mentioned [here] (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). So it can have require method calls. Moreover if config.js is the **data-main** then it should contain code that initializes your app.